# QuerySet ManyToMany и генератор списка

Tags: python-3.x, django

Таким образом создаю два списка:

```
devices = []
for i in context['services']:
    for z in i.devices.all():
        devices.append(z)

spare_parts = []
for i in context['services']:
    for z in i.spare_parts.all():
        spare_parts.append(z)
```

Хочу для краткости и красоты, сделать это при помощи генератора, но не получается.

Пробую делать так:

```
[k for k in [[z for z in i.devices.all()] for i in context['services']]]
[k for k in [[z for z in i.spare_parts.all()] for i in context['services']]]
```

Но получаю такой результат:

```
[[<Device: asdasd>], []]
[[], []]
```

А нужен такой:

```
[<Device: asdasd>]
[]
```

Какие бы способы не пробовал с генератором, всегда остаются лишние скобки. Практически в любом случае, получаю список `QuerySet'ов`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, так

```
devices = [z for i in context['services'] for z in i.devices.all()]
share_parts = [z for i in context['services'] for z in i.spare_parts.all()]
```